# Laravel 8: Create function to render template given a template name and directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

What would be correct code inside this function for it to work correctly, even if called twice in the same request?

```
     function get_html($dir, $templateName, $templateVars)
     {
         $viewFinder = View::getFinder();

         $oldPaths = $viewFinder->getPaths();

         $viewFinder->setPaths( [$dir]);

         $newHTML = view($templateName, $templateVars)->render();

         $viewFinder->setPaths($oldPaths);

         return $newHTML;                  
     }
```

Intended input: a view directory/path and a template name, e.g. "standard", template vars

Intended output: the rendered template.

Current problem: If called with the code below:

```
$html_one = get_html($dir_one, 'standard', []);
$html_two = get_html($dir_two, 'standard', []);
```

Both $html_one and $html_two will contain the rendered standard.blade.php template from $dir_one.  Laravel will ignore the standard.blade.php template in $dir_two.

Answer (score 0):

Have to flush the template cache or else it will use the same template as last time if you pass in the same name.

```
 function get_html($dir, $templateName, $templateVars)
 {
     $viewFinder = View::getFinder();

     $oldPaths = $viewFinder->getPaths();

     $viewFinder->setPaths( [$dir]);

     $viewFinder->flush();  // here

     $newHTML = view($templateName, $templateVars)->render();

     $viewFinder->setPaths($oldPaths);

     return $newHTML;                  
 }
```